# How to divide Javascript dynamic variable by a number

Tags: javascript, html, variables, e-commerce, shopify

I am trying to add a feature to my e-commerce website, where under the price it says pay over 4 easy installments of (total price / 4) over 8 weeks.

Can someone help me write this?

Currently it says:

```
 <p class="afterpay-text">Make 4 easy payments of ***** over 8 weeks...</p>
```

And the variable is `{{ variant.price | money }}`

Thanks

Comment: um... `variable = variable / 4;` ??

Comment: <p class="afterpay-text">Make 4 easy payments of *** over 8 weeks...</p> is the current statement

Comment: tried {{ variant.price/4 | money }} didnt work

Comment: adding brackets made it a text field didnt work either lol i tried the basic logics i knw from SQL coding but none of them worked

Comment: this has nothing to do with SQL. go to your javascript file, and just divide your variable by 4... `variant.price = variant.price / 4;`

Comment: Dynamic variable is in javascript or php?

Comment: From your {{}} syntax, I assume you're using Angular. Is that correct? Could you share some controller code?

Comment: You should probably tell us what template-system you use, or at least wich e-commerce solution (it may reference the templating-solution). It may help to understand what your snippets actually mean.

Comment: Mani and Cobus sorry not sure the answer ro both your questions. I am looking at the HTML editor on the back of my website e-commerce platform which is Shopify

Comment: here is the full section           
          </div>
     <p class="afterpay-text">Make 4 easy payments over 8 weeks...</p>

         <a href="https://www.afterpay.com.au/buy-with-afterpay/"
          target="_blank" style="display: block;max- width:400px;">
          <img src="http://static.secure-afterpay.com.au/banner.svg"
          style="width: 100%;"></img>
          </a>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using angular with the double curly braces and filter? if so...

```
  $scope.spreadPayment = function(){
  //+variant.price converts it to a number(leave it out if it is already a number)
//just replace price with your variable
var price = 100;
var quarterOfPrice = price /4;
var weeklyPayments = quarterOfPrice / 2;

return weeklyPayments;
```

}

```
<p>Make 4 easy payments of {{spreadPayment() | currency}} over 8 weeks...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{{ variant.price | divided_by: 4 | money }}
```